# Why is 'print function' printing the last number iterated by the 'for loop'?

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop

```
array = [1,2,3,3,3,3,9,4,5]
 
for number in range(1,length(array)+1):
     pass
 print(number) #This here print "9"
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What *else* what you have expected to be printed? What value would you assume ``number`` to have after the loop?

Comment: MisterMiyagi .. i expected that due to pass statement nothing will be printed..

Comment: The ``pass`` statement literally has no effect. Why would it affect the ``print`` which isn't even in the loop?

Comment: As 9 gets printed, that means for loop *in this case* will always print the last iterated value(of the loop)?

Comment: I recommend you read up on how Python's for loop is defined. The behaviour is not related to (or affected by) ``pass`` or ``print``.

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is actually used for when the person wants to make a while loop or for loop etc to be empty or to do **nothing** in the loop..What you did is after the `pass` statement you put a `print` statement so the python Interpreter simply passes through the for loop doing nothing and at the end of the  for loop the value of **number** becomes **9** so it is printed by the followed statement `print(number)` .

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..

Comment: You're welcome! BTW don't call me **sir** :-P

Comment: @Ritiksharma If you found my answer helpful then can you accept my answer my answer by clicking on the checkmark button?

Answer (score 0):

The `pass` statement in Python does not work like a comment. The compiler will simply "pass" the `pass` statement and move on to the next which, in this case, is the `print`.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering...

Answer (score 0):

print function will print whatever instruction will be given to it.
Here range is playing role in printing the number.

array size is 9 in your example and as per range function definition "it generate a sequence of integers from start (including)  to end (excluding) by step."

So as we have a input for number in range(1,len(array)+1):

so it will start from 1 to 10 and your program will be like
array = [1,2,3,3,3,3,9,4,5]
for number in range(1,len(array)+1):
pass
print(number)

So number will be having 9 as a last value to hold and print that's why it is printing 9.

Comment: Okayy thank you saurabh..